# cannot move ‘/home/vagrant/.config/psysh_history’

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I am using homestead..Suddenly when I use tinker I have this error message:

> PsySH history file found at '/home/vagrant/.config/psysh_history'.
>   Please delete it or move it   to
>   '/home/vagrant/.config/psysh/psysh_history'.

but when I tried to move it.
    mv /home/vagrant/.config/psysh_history /home/vagrant/.config/psysh/psysh_history

it says:

> Cannot move ‘/home/vagrant/.config/psysh_history’ to
>   ‘/home/vagrant/.config/psysh/psysh_history’: No such file or directory

Where I make mystake? Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `cd /home/vagrant/.config` then `mkdir psysh` then `mv psysh_history psysh/psysh_history`